# How to prove that division is cancellative?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I want to prove that `(c * a) / (c * b) = a / b` in agda using the division function defined in the standard library. The proofs keep coming back to this thing `div-helper` that is very difficult to work with and reason about.

```
open import Data.Nat.DivMod using (_/_)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; suc; zero)

/-cancelˡ : ∀ c a b {b≢0} {b*c≢0} → ((c * a) / (c * b)) {b*c≢0} ≡ (a / b) {b≢0}
/-cancelˡ (suc c) a (suc b) {b≢0} {b*c≢0} = ?
```

That hole simplifies to:

```
div-helper 0 (b + c * suc b) (a + c * a) (b + c * suc b) ≡ div-helper 0 b a b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could come up with two different proofs.

- Proof 1 is completely agnostic of `div-helper`'s structure. It is based on lemmas about division from the standard library. It proves a few additional lemmas about division, which it then uses to prove the property we're after. It's a little involved, but I think that the additional lemmas are useful in their own right.
- Proof 2 considers the structure of `div-helper` and proves two invariants from which the property follows trivially. It's way more concise.

This is the property we're after:

`∀ (a b n : ℕ) → divₕ 0 (b + n + b * n) (a + n * a) (b + n + b * n) ≡ divₕ 0 b a b`

What makes this look a little weird is that the division helper takes `n` (as opposed to `suc n`) for `a / suc n`. That's where `b + n + b * n` comes from - `suc (b + n + b * n)` is equal to `suc b * suc n`.

Stated in terms of `/` instead of the division helper, the proof thus says that `(a * suc n) / (suc b * suc n)` is equal to `a / suc b`.

This is proof 1:

```
module Answer where

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as P using (_≡_; cong; refl; subst; sym)

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Data.Nat.DivMod.Core
open import Data.Nat.Properties

open import Agda.Builtin.Nat using () renaming (div-helper to divₕ; mod-helper to modₕ)

divₕ′ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
divₕ′ a m = divₕ 0 m a m

modₕ′ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
modₕ′ a m = modₕ 0 m a m

a<n⇒a[divₕ]n≡0 : ∀ (a n n′ : ℕ) → a ≤ n → divₕ 0 n′ a n ≡ 0
a<n⇒a[divₕ]n≡0 zero _ _ _ = refl
a<n⇒a[divₕ]n≡0 (suc a) (suc n) n′ (s≤s a≤n) = a<n⇒a[divₕ]n≡0 a n n′ a≤n

a*n[modₕ]n≡0 : ∀ (a n : ℕ) → modₕ 0 n (a * suc n) n ≡ 0
a*n[modₕ]n≡0 zero n = refl
a*n[modₕ]n≡0 (suc a) n rewrite +-comm (suc n) (a * suc n) | a+n[modₕ]n≡a[modₕ]n 0 (a * suc n) n = a*n[modₕ]n≡0 a n

a<n⇒a+b*n[divₕ]n≡b : ∀ (a b n : ℕ) → a ≤ n → divₕ 0 n (a + b * suc n) n ≡ b
a<n⇒a+b*n[divₕ]n≡b a b n a≤n =
  begin
    divₕ′ (a + b * suc n) n
  ≡⟨ +-distrib-divₕ 0 0 a (b * suc n) n lem₁ ⟩
    divₕ′ a n + divₕ′ (b * suc n) n
  ≡⟨ cong (_+ divₕ′ (b * suc n) n) (a<n⇒a[divₕ]n≡0 a n n a≤n) ⟩
    0 + divₕ′ (b * suc n) n
  ≡⟨ +-identityˡ (divₕ 0 n (b * suc n) n) ⟩
    divₕ′ (b * suc n) n
  ≡⟨ m*n/n≡m b (suc n) ⟩
    b
  ∎

  where

  open P.≡-Reasoning

  ≤₁ = a[modₕ]n<n 0 a n
  ≤₂ = ≤-reflexive (a*n[modₕ]n≡0 b n)

  <₃ : n + 0 < suc n
  <₃ = s≤s (≤-reflexive (+-identityʳ n))

  lem₁ : modₕ′ a n + modₕ′ (b * suc n) n < suc n
  lem₁ = <-transʳ (+-mono-≤ ≤₁ ≤₂) <₃ 

a[divₕ]m*n≡a[divₕ]m[divₕ]n : ∀ (a m n : ℕ) → divₕ 0 (m + n + m * n) a (m + n + m * n) ≡ divₕ 0 n (divₕ 0 m a m) n
a[divₕ]m*n≡a[divₕ]m[divₕ]n a m n =
  begin
    divₕ′ a mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ # mn) (div-mod-lemma 0 0 a m) ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + divₕ′ a m * suc m) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + # * suc m) mn) (div-mod-lemma 0 0 (divₕ′ a m) n) ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + (modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc n) * suc m) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + #) mn) (*-distribʳ-+ (suc m) (modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n) (divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc n)) ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + (modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc n * suc m)) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ # mn) (sym (+-assoc (modₕ′ a m) (modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m) (divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc n * suc m))) ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc n * suc m) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + #) mn) (*-assoc (divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n) (suc n) (suc m))⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * (suc n * suc m)) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * #) mn) (*-comm (suc n) (suc m)) ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * (suc m * suc n)) mn
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * #) mn) lem₁ ⟩
    divₕ′ (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m + divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc mn) mn
  ≡⟨ a<n⇒a+b*n[divₕ]n≡b (modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m) (divₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n) mn lem₄ ⟩
    divₕ 0 n (divₕ′ a m) n
  ∎

  where

  open P.≡-Reasoning

  mn = m + n + m * n

  lem₁ : suc m * suc n ≡ suc mn
  lem₁ rewrite +-comm m n | *-comm m (suc n) | *-comm m n | +-assoc n m (n * m) = refl

  lem₂ : m + n * suc m ≡ mn
  lem₂ rewrite *-comm n (suc m) | +-assoc m n (m * n) = refl

  ≤₁ = a[modₕ]n<n 0 a m
  ≤₂ = a[modₕ]n<n 0 (divₕ 0 m a m) n
  ≤₃ = ≤-refl {suc m}

  lem₃ = +-mono-≤ ≤₁ (*-mono-≤ ≤₂ ≤₃)

  lem₄ : modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m ≤ mn
  lem₄ = subst (λ # → modₕ′ a m + modₕ′ (divₕ′ a m) n * suc m ≤ #) lem₂ lem₃

a*n[divₕ]b*n≡a[divₕ]b : ∀ (a b n : ℕ) → divₕ 0 (b + n + b * n) (a + n * a) (b + n + b * n) ≡ divₕ 0 b a b
a*n[divₕ]b*n≡a[divₕ]b a b n =
  begin
    divₕ′ na nb
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ na #) nb≡bn ⟩
    divₕ′ na bn
  ≡⟨ a[divₕ]m*n≡a[divₕ]m[divₕ]n na n b ⟩
    divₕ′ (divₕ′ na n) b
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ (divₕ′ # n) b) lem₁ ⟩
    divₕ′ (divₕ′ (a * suc n) n) b
  ≡⟨ cong (λ # → divₕ′ # b) (a*n[divₕ]n≡a 0 a n) ⟩
    divₕ 0 b a b
  ∎

  where

  open P.≡-Reasoning

  na = a + n * a

  nb = b + n + b * n
  bn = n + b + n * b

  nb≡bn : nb ≡ bn
  nb≡bn rewrite +-comm n b | *-comm n b = refl

  lem₁ : na ≡ a * suc n
  lem₁ rewrite *-comm a (suc n) = refl
```

Now let's look at proof 2. Simply append it to the above code, so that I don't have to repeat the `import`s:

```
a*n[divₕ]b*n≡a[divₕ]b′ : ∀ (a b n : ℕ) → divₕ 0 (b + n + b * n) (a + n * a) (b + n + b * n) ≡ divₕ 0 b a b
a*n[divₕ]b*n≡a[divₕ]b′ a b n rewrite +-comm b n | *-comm b n = lem₂ n 0 b a b

  where

  lem₁ : ∀ (a k m n j : ℕ) → divₕ k m (a + n) (a + j) ≡ divₕ k m n j
  lem₁ zero k m n j = refl
  lem₁ (suc a) k m n j = lem₁ a k m n j

  lem₂ : ∀ (a k m n j : ℕ) → divₕ k (a + m + a * m) (suc a * n) (a + j + a * j) ≡ divₕ k m n j
  lem₂ a k m zero j rewrite *-zeroʳ a = refl

  lem₂ a k m (suc n) zero
    rewrite *-zeroʳ a
            | +-identityʳ a
            | *-suc a n
            | P.sym (+-assoc n a (a * n))
            | +-comm n a
            | +-assoc a n (a * n)
            | P.sym (+-suc a (n + a * n))
            | lem₁ a k (a + m + a * m) (suc (n + a * n)) 0
            = lem₂ a (suc k) m n m

  lem₂ a k m (suc n) (suc j)
    rewrite *-suc a n
            | P.sym (+-assoc n a (a * n))
            | +-comm n a
            | +-assoc a n (a * n)
            | P.sym (+-suc a (n + a * n))
            | +-assoc a (suc j) (a * suc j)
            | lem₁ a k (a + m + a * m) (suc (n + a * n)) (suc j + a * suc j)
            | *-suc a j
            | P.sym (+-assoc j a (a * j))
            | +-comm j a
            = lem₂ a k m n j
```

The first lemma is an invariant that says that we can add an identical value `a` to the last two arguments of `div-helper`, `n` and `j`. It's used by the second lemma, which is the more interesting one.

The second lemma is an invariant that says that you can multiply the last three arguments, `m`, `n`, and `j`, with an identical value `a`. Its a proof by induction on the last two arguments, `n` and `j`. This makes it closely follow the structure of `div-helper`.

The proof thus covers the same three different cases that show up in the three defining equations of `div-helper`:

- `n` is zero
- `n` is non-zero, but `j` is zero
- `n` and `j` are both non-zero

The property that we're after then follows directly from the second lemma. This is basically the idea outlined in the other response, where the second lemma is the more general version of the property that we're after.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the invariants `div-helper` respects are spelt out in the builtin file [`Agda.Builtin.Nat`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Agda.Builtin.Nat.html). You should state a more general version of your lemma satisfied by `div-helper`.